# Closed Q merge request

Tags: support, merged-questions

I've just [had a Q closed for being a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090674/windows-api-hooks-used-by-av-software). While I don't dispute the close, I actually think the answers I got were better than on the original.

Is there anyway they can be moved across?

Comment: It's called merging; you can flag for mod attention and ask them to do it

Comment: I'd read other Qs on here saying it needed a mod to do it but hadn't realised flagging was the way to go. Thanks

Comment: A bad thing with merging (possibly I am thinking of questions closed as `exact duplicates of`) is new questions merged with _old questions with no answers_. Meaning, a much much lower probability to get a response in due time.